point cloud registration - how to mark boundary of object?
I have a point cloud registration problem, where I'm trying to compare 3D scannings of various archaeological artifacts.
I have already downsampled my point clouds to be on regular voxel grids, and I also have my registration pipeline set up with global registration (RANSAC) followed by local registration (ICP). But one issue that I just realized is that my point clouds only mark the object but not actually the boundary to air.
This means that if I were to compare a brooche with an intricate pattern on it I would get 100% match to a big point cloud cube, since t he brooche fits perfectly inside the cube.
How can I prevent this kind of false matching where "fine" objects just fits perfectly inside "fatter" objects.
My own thinking would be to somehow also include a thin air band around the objects, and all the air points should then have a different property and only match against other air points. But when looking at for instance open3D I do not see any properties to make this kind of comparison possible. So how is this normally done?
